# How to enable HSTS header for HTTPS only in lighttpd config?

Tags: http-headers, lighttpd, hsts

I want to enable HSTS header for my lighttpd server. As per the [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/lighttpd-setup-hsts-http-strict-transport-security/) article, the HSTS header does get set, but I can see that the server sends this header even in responses over HTTP (non-secure transport). As specified in RFC 6797:

> An HSTS Host MUST NOT include the STS header field in HTTP response
> conveyed over non-secure transport.

How do I disable this header for non-secure HTTP responses?

Answer (score 0):

```
server.modules += ( "mod_setenv" )
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
  setenv.set-response-header = ( "Strict-Transport-Security" => "max-age=SECONDS"  )
}
```

(replace SECONDS with a value appropriate for your site policy)

See lighttpd documentation for [mod_setenv](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModSetEnv) for additional policy examples.

If you set site policy headers globally in lighttpd, but you redirect all http traffic to https and want to disable sending policy headers with those redirects (and you used `setenv.set-response-header` as above):

```
server.modules += ( "mod_setenv", "mod_redirect" )
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  setenv.set-response-header = ()
  url.redirect = ("" => "https://${url.authority}${url.path}${qsa}")
  url.redirect-code = 308
}
```